# Queuing Discipline and Lipschitz Continuity

Tags: microeconomics

I was [reading a paper](https://editorialexpress.com/cgi-bin/conference/download.cgi?db_name=SSCWatBC&paper_id=150) by *Platz and Østerdal* (2014) titled "**The curse of the first-in-first-out queue discipline**". I was wondering about a particular section of it, particularly the part about last-in-first-out mechanisms. $R(t)$ is defined as the cumulative arrival distribution, and they try and show:

> *Let $R(t)$ be a Nash Equilibrium for the FIFO (first-in-first-out) queue discipline. Then $R(t)$ is Lipschitz continuous.*

This is the second Lemma on page 2.

I am not quite understanding why we are trying to show this property to lead into the third Lemma. What is the importance of Lipschitz continuity here? A basic intuitive answer should be okay, but some math would help me I think. Are they trying to ultimately show that $R(t)$ is a unique Nash equilibrium for FIFO?

Comment: I couldn't open the paper.

Comment: @MarceloGelati That's what older me gets for not putting in the author and title. I updated the link. Should work now.

Comment: Are you still interested in the question?

Comment: Hell yeah buddy

Comment: It appears that Lipschitz  continuity is used later mostly related to the LIFO queue results. Moreover, Lipschitz  continuity is used in fixed point theorems, and Nash Equilibrium is essentially a definition of a fixed point.

Comment: I understand it in another way; perhaps these two sentences might help: "For an agent arriving at a time $t$ where $R(t)$ has no jump, the time of service is deterministic" and "note that [...] Lemma 3 implies that $R$ has no jumps for $t > 0$". I mean, if the function is Lipschitz continuous, you get a deterministic time of service and because of that you can guarantee lemma 4; otherwise, you couldn't.

Comment: Lipschitz continuity is used to proff that $R(t)$ is absolutely continuous an then the following formula holds: $R(t) = R(0) + \int_0^t r_+(t)\text{d}t$